# What's the difference between `linux-oem` and `linux-oem-osp1` kernels, and how are they versioned?

Tags: package-management, kernel, oem

I understand from reading [Kernel/OEMKernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/OEMKernel) that the `linux-oem` kernel package is supposed to be a more up-to-date kernel package, that includes additional hardware compatibility tweaks for supported devices on top of the standard kernel (`linux-generic`?). I'm currently running Ubuntu 19.04 and I note that in addition, the package repositories also contain a `linux-oem-osp1` metapackage.

Also, the version number of the kernel associated with the `linux-oem` package appears to suggest it is *older* than the kernel for `linux-generic`, which seems contrary to the description in the linked documentation above.

For Ubuntu Desktop 19.04, as of 2019-10-19, the versions appear as follows:

- `linux-generic` - 5.0.0.32.33
- `linux-oem` - 4.15.0.1056.60
- `linux-oem-osp1` - 5.0.0.1024.27

So, my questions are:

1. What's the difference between `linux-oem` and `linux-oem-osp1`?
2. How are both of these packages versioned (in particular, why does `linux-oem` appear to be based on an older kernel than `linux-generic`)?

Comment: Interesting, i flipped may pages still no tail to hold. no description on package page neither in source code, also a question there about meaning of osp1 just expired.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously the "osp1"-package has a later build number, that let's one assume that "sp1" may be a label for "service pack one" or something like that.

However, since the is no official info in the wiki about any regulations how such service releases are made, I would recommend to ask the kernel devs directly via the mailing-list [here](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/kernel-team).

HTH

Comment: Good suggestion. Since the question is a bit old (although it looks like the OP may be active), perhaps, if you feel like it, you could ask on the mailing list yourself and update your answer if you get a response.